# Youtube Live-streaming API returns an empty list of streams

Tags: youtube-livestreaming-api

I'm trying to make an electron app that will work together with OBS. For this I need the Stream Name from youtube among other things.
But this stream name has proven hard to get from the API.

I'm currently testing it with the python examples on the documentation page.
[This is the example that i use.](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveStreams/list?authuser=1)

Before I started, I created a event with all the settings - and I'm able to see the Stream Name/Key on the website.

When I use the API, it just returns an empty list. I'm sure that I do have a stream, and that it's working as I created it myself, and I am streaming to the example view.

However I never get anything from that service. The other services work, like the list broadcasts one, it returns all planned events.

List Broadcasts:

```
$ python .\list_broadcasts.py
Broadcasts with status 'all':
Test Begivenhed (ib08ZcLQgZA)
```

List Streams:

```
$ python .\list_streams.py
Live streams:
```

The code for the examples can also be found here: https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/tree/master/python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that when you create a "Broadcast" a random stream is attached. It's impossible to get the key from this stream.

Instead you need to create a new "Stream/Customised Ingestion", this will make it all work, just make sure that your broadcast is attached with the steam.

You can reuse this stream, and that's a good thing for me, as I don't need to change the streaming key all the time.

You can create a new Stream/Customised Ingestion preset in the UI or via the API.

[image]
[image]